# AWK replace $0 of second file when match few columns

Tags: regex, bash, awk

How I merge two files when two first columns match in both files and replace first file values with second file columns... I mean...

Same number of columns:

```
FILE 1:
121212,0100,1.1,1.2,
121212,0200,2.1,2.2,

FILE 2:
121212,0100,3.1,3.2,3.3,
121212,0130,4.1,4.2,4.3,
121212,0200,5.1,5.2,5.3,
121212,0230,6.1,6.2,6.3,

OUTPUT:
121212,0100,3.1,3.2,3.3,
121212,0200,5.1,5.2,5.3,
```

In other words, I need to print `$0` of the second file when match `$1` and `$2` in both files. I understand the logic but I can't implement it using arrays. That apparently should be used.

Please take a moment to explain any code.

Comment: Check http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/file-comparisons-using-awk-match-columns.html or this:http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/awk-one-liner-for-multi-column.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `awk` to print the first 2 fields in the pattern file and pipe to `grep` to do the match:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}{print $1,$2}' file1 | grep -f - file2
121212,0100,3.1,3.2,3.3,
121212,0200,5.1,5.2,5.3,
```

The `-f` option tells `grep` to take the pattern from a file but using `-` instead of a filename makes `grep` take the patterns from `stdin`.

So the first `awk` script produces the patterns from `file1` which we pipe to match against in `file2` using `grep`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}{print $1,$2}' file1
121212,0100
121212,0200
```

You probably want to anchor the match to the beginning of the line using `^`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}{print "^"$1,$2}' file1 
^121212,0100
^121212,0200

$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}{print "^"$1,$2}' file1 | grep -f - file2
121212,0100,3.1,3.2,3.3,
121212,0200,5.1,5.2,5.3,
```

Comment: Clever way to solve this. Thanks for all. Now I can go to prepare holidays. And is fast enough to batch long files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR { a[$1,$2]; next } ($1,$2) in a' file1 file2
```

Results:

```
121212,0100,3.1,3.2,3.3,
121212,0200,5.1,5.2,5.3,
```